# Are there two or three Rabbi Rashash?

Tags: history

How many Rabbi's are there that are named "Rashash"? I can't seem to find any sources that speak of another rashash, besides the ones mentioned below. I was told that there was one that lived a thousand years ago. Who is that person?

I know of the Rashash of [Shalom Sharabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalom_Sharabi) and [Shtrason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Strashun).

I was told that there was on who lived before the Arizal the one who invented the Kavanot that the Arizal uses in his book.

Comment: If you know one already, you should edit into your question who that is.

Comment: @magicker72, The question was edited though the question is self evident, as neither of the rashas that are well know lived a thousand years ago. And the question is asking for the man who live a thousand years ago.

Comment: Both lived after the ARI and R. Strason was no a Mequbal and didn't believe in Metemplychosis. R. Shaarabi was a scholar of a Cabalistic school that followed the ARI line.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that the person who told you this misunderstood, Rabbi Shalom Sharabi (the Rashash) commentated on the works of the Ari, zl, and wrote a siddur (Siddur Ha-Kavanot) known for its Kavanot, that is used by many kabbalistic jews; the Ari never published a siddur.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the main ones are the two mentioned in your original post. Rabbi Samuel Strashun is best known as a commentator on the Talmud. [Rabbi Shalom Sharabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalom_Sharabi) was an 18th Century post-Lurianic Kabbalist. Depending on whether you are in a Talmudic context or a Kabbalistic one usually one of those is usually called "the Rashash."

In some circles, Rashash can also refer to the eighteenth century Yemenite poet [Rabbi Shalom Shabazi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalom_Shabazi). Finally, I have on occasion seen [Rabbi Shimon Shkop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimon_Shkop) (19th-20th century talmudist) abbreviated in writing as Rashash, though I have never heard him called that in conversation.

As for *"I was told that there was one that lived a thousand years ago,"* it would not shock me if there was some Rishon abbreviated Rashash (e.g., Rabbi Shimon of [some place starting with sin or shin]), but I am not aware of one and couldn't find one one Google.

As for someone who invented kavanot used by the Arizal, it ssound like a confused description of Rav Sharabi, as BID points out in their answer. Rashash Sharabi was post-Arizal and built on his kabbalistic system. It's also possible the person you were speaking to mixed up the Rashash and Rashbi. Rashbi refers to [Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimon_bar_Yochai), a rabbi in the Talmud later treated as a mystical figure and author of the Zohar. The Ari believed the Zohar was written by Rashbi and refers to him often.

Comment: רבי שמשון משאנץ

Comment: That would make sense. I was thinking of naming him but didn't want to give the false impression that I was saying he was actually called Rashash. Have you seen somewhere where he is called Rashash or abbreviated as sush? Wouldn't surprise me.